# Show that $\left \lfloor\log_{2}\left( \lfloor x \right \rfloor)\right \rfloor=\left \lfloor{\log_{2}(x)}\right \rfloor $

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I am having some trouble constructing a proof for this equality. Here is what I have tried so far:

Show that $\left \lfloor\log_{2}\left( \lfloor x \right \rfloor)\right \rfloor=\left \lfloor{\log_{2}(x)}\right \rfloor $

Proof:

$\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor=m\iff x-1<m\leq x\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (1)$

Let $x-1<m\leq x \rightarrow\left \lfloor\log_{2}(  m \right) \rfloor=\left \lfloor{\log_{2}(x)}\right \rfloor \;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$

From $(1)$ we can see $x−1<m≤x\rightarrow m=\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \;\;\;(3)$

Let $m=x\rightarrow \left \lfloor{\log_{2}(x)}\right \rfloor=\left \lfloor{\log_{2}(x)}\right \rfloor \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(4)$

These statements are identical, thus $\left \lfloor\log_{2}\left( \lfloor x \right \rfloor)\right \rfloor=\left \lfloor{\log_{2}(x)}\right \rfloor $

$\square$

Comment: Why is 2) true?  What if $\log_2 m < k \le \log_2 x$ for some integer $k$? Why can't that happen.  (Also you never stated that $m$ is actually an integer).

Comment: @fleablood I saw this issue, however, this is the only "proof" I have been able come up with. I am on the right track? Are there any hints you can think of to push me in the right direction?

Comment: Also what if $\lfloor x \rfloor \le 0$?

Comment: You are on the right track.  But *EXPLAIN* why $x - 1 < m \le x \implies [\log_2 m] =[\log_2 x]$.

Comment: I'd say though that statement is *not* true for all $x$ and is it not true for $0< x< 1$.  (It's *vacuously* true, at best, if $x \le 0$....) It *was* the responsibility of the creator of the question to indicate that $x \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to state *why* if $m \le x$ then $\log_2 m \le \log_2 x$ but why that means there can't be an integer $k$ so that $\log_2 m < k \le \log_2 x$.

The reason for that would be that if $\log_2 m < k \le \log 2 x$ then $m < 2^k \le x$.

As $2^k$ is an integer we must have, in this case, $2^k= x$ and $x$ is an integer and $m = 2^k = x$ and $[\log_2 (x)] = [k] = k = \log_2 x = \log_2 [x]$.

....

TO put it together I'd do the following.

If $x \le 0$ then neither $\log_2 x$ nor $\log_2 [x]$ are defined.

However if $0 < x < 1$ the statement is not true as $\log_2 x$ exist (and is negative) but $\log_2 [x]=\log_2 0 $ is undefined.

Now if $x\ge 1$ then there is a distinct integer $m$ so that $m \le x < m+1$ and $m = [x]$.  Also, as $m \ge 1$ there is unique non-negative integer $k$ so that $2^k \le m \le x < m+1 \le 2^{k+1}$.

ANd now we've nailed it!

$2^k \le [c]\le x < 2^{k+1}$.

So $k \le \log_2 [x] \le \log_2 (x) < k+1$.

So that means $[\log_2(x) ]$ and $[\log_2[x]] $ are both equal to the same integer; $k$.

(In essence.  If $k \ge 0$ then differences between $2^k$ and $2^{k+1}$ is always greater or equal to $1$ (equal only if $k=0$), so the difference between the log (base $2$) of integers must always less than or equal to $1$ (equal only if the integers are $1$ and $2$).